# JPA OneToOne association without foreign key not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate/JPA, and have 3 tables:

```
Contact
pk contact_id
fk member_id

Employee
pk employee_id
fk member_id

Members
pk member_id
```

I have:

```
@Entity(name = "Contact" )
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "contact_sequence", sequenceName = "contact_ids")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "contact_sequence")
    private java.lang.Long contact_id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Members.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    private Members member;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member", referencedColumnName = "member")
    private Employee employee;
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "employee_sequence", sequenceName = "employee_ids")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_sequence")
    private java.lang.Long employee_id;
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "Members")
@Table(name = "Members")
public class Members implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "members_sequence", sequenceName = "member_ids")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "members_sequence")
    private java.lang.Long member_id;
```

My problem is with the `Contact` entity `private Employee employee;`. When I start my Jboss server:

> StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.

**Question**

How do I annotate the `private Employee employee;` on the `Contact` entity?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are almost properly defining the `private Members member;`, so is there a reason for not doing the same for `private Employee employee;` ?

Like :

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee", referencedColumnName = "employee_id")
private Employee employee;
```

Also a simple [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column), just to cross-check the overall `@JoinColumn` functionality

===EDIT===

As it looks there is indeed a data structure issue as from the first place the relation is ManyToOne,

If you could try the below example :

```
//Employee
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "contact_id")
    private Contact contact;

//Contact
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employee_id")
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then by selecting the `contact.getEmployees()` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still get the same error when the server starts up.

Comment: could you share a snippet from the error's stack trace?

Comment: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: employee in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(Employee) and its related supertables and secondary tables

Comment: hmm maybe that was my bad as i was still editing, did you tried the last one with `@JoinColumn(name = "employee", referencedColumnName = "employee_id")`

Comment: Yes, I tried what you say above, I am just about to give the following a try: `@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "employee_id")` now.

Comment: ye try that, because the error is a bit awkward. Are you sure that the database and all packages are properly mapped? just for the record, which hibernate are u using? and also, are u delivering that along with your app, or you depend on JBoss's hibernate?

Comment: With `@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "employee_id")`, I now get no errors, but the `Employee` object is `null` (should not be as there is data).  I am using hibernate 1.2.0.Final (I can't upgrade as it's an existing app). I am dependent on JBoss, as this is a large old app to which I am adding a new feature.

Comment: thats because the fetch type is lazy, if you want to have it all the time make it eager, otherwise you have to call `contant.getEmployee()`

Comment: I think that works, because now I get `javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements`

Comment: good, then change it to `ManyToOne` and keep the List Reference

Comment: Very strange, I have changed it to: `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`. Now my Employee is still null.

Comment: are u sure that the data are proper in the database?

Comment: Yes, because when I run the SQL alone, i.e. using a JOIN, it does have data.  But this is strange because why would there previously be a `NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements` if the data is `null`.

Comment: This works:  `SELECT employee.* FROM contact 
INNER JOIN members ON members.member_id = contact.member_id 
INNER JOIN employee ON  employee.member_id = contact.member_id 
WHERE contact.email = 'info@email.com'`

Comment: ok thats one contact, are u sure you are fetching the right one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: in your code, while you are getting the error, could you see for which row you are getting that? its smelling mostly like a data issue

Comment: I changed it back to `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`, and now I don't get the `NonUniqueResultException`, but the Employee is null.  I am a bit confused why it's different now.

Comment: as said, please cross check the full contact table with all foreign relations, soundsmostly like a data issue, or maybe are u connecting to another DB? cant really say without having at least a sample code / conf

Comment: It looks like `@joinformula` would work, but unfortunately it's not available with my version of hibernate (1.2.0.Final).

Comment: oh, i got your issue, you have to maintain the one to many table on your own.... can be a pain, but in reality you just introduce another table, i am editing my answer as well.

Comment: It is a @OneToOne relationship. I have just tried to use `@SqlResultSetMapping` with no success. I can populate the other objects, but not the employee.  (I have a complex structure which I think is making things difficult ).  I am now looking to see if I can get hibernate/jpa to perform a select on the column just like `@joinformula` in 1.2.0.Final.